# Getting endpoint states of robot

Tags: ros, pose, callback, rostopic-echo, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using a Baxter and I want to get the endpoint states of my robot. The endpoint states are located in the topic

```
/robot/limb/left/endpoint_state
```

and on the terminal I can echo this topic to get the endpoint states. Running this would yield:

```
pose:
position:
x: some double
y: some double
z: some double
orientation:
...
```

I only need the pose x y and z position data. My guess is to get this, I need to subscribe to this topic, but I'm not sure how I would subscribe to it to get just that data.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182447/getting-endpoint-states-of-robot/) by [grisam](https://answers.ros.org/users/18776/grisam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two ways to do this:

1. subscribe to the topic. This is the easy way. I highly recommend this method as apposed to the following. You will just take the message and use the parts you need. If you are using C++ or Java, you will use the variables like you would a struct.
2. Please don't do this to yourself... The other method would be to interpret the echo as a string, and parse through it. This is extremely unnecessary, and will only slow things down.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grisam](https://answers.ros.org/users/18776/grisam/) on 2014-07-02**:
I have no intention of doing the latter, and I've been stuck on number 1. for a couple days now. When I subscribe to the topic, how do I only extract the information I need, i.e. the x y and z of the pose? As in how would the callback work?